# Debian Packaging: Different configuration per subpackage

Tags: linux, cmake, debian, packaging

I have a CMake-based project with a static library (by default) where I need to provide deb-packages. I want to make it nice and provide a shared and a static library in different packages.

Then: How can I pass different configuration-options from the `debian/rules` to the underlying cmake for the `lib$packagename` and the `lib$packagename-dev` package? Say, in this example, switch cmake to build a shared library via `CMAKE_FLAGS+=-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON`?

I don't find that many examples for the more recent debhelper format (which is 9 in my case). Is it recommended to use an earlier version for this specific requirement?

Thanks and Greetings